# git rebase subfolder between branch

Tags: git, github

I'm working on linux kernel, i have two branches v4.14 and v4.18.

I want to pull certain subfolder from v4.18 to v4.14 with original committer id and commit message.

i have tried following ways:

1-> v4.14 $ git checkout v4.18 /path/to/subfolder -> pull all files but doesn't hold commit history.

2-> v4.14 $ git rebase v4.18 --> It will pull patches but not as expected as i want.

3-> v4.18 $ git filter-branch --subdirectory-folder /path/to/subfolder

3rd one works fine but it will pull entire history which is unnecessary. I want to pull changes until it reaches common reference commits id.

I want to limit git filter-branch till particular commit-id.

(or)

If anyone has the better idea please do share.